# filestream fulltext-index language-for-wordbreaker

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, filestream

I need to use "_" as a word breaker for full text search. Setting the language as Korean does what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('Happy_Hour',1042,0,0)
```

When I put "'Happy_Hour' inside a txt file and have a column FileStream for this file content, setting Korean as Language-Word-Breaker doesn't work  for FullText Search indexing  on the FileStream column. I  was using `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_position_by_document` to check the indexed keywords, only "Happy_Hour" is indexed.

Any ideas?